# What are the possible solutions for the linker errors I face while building a Rust kernel for x86_64 arch in OSDev?

Tags: rust, x86, linker, rust-cargo, osdev

I am trying to build a rust kernel, however i am facing severe issues with the linker, can someone please suggest any solns for this problem. Thank you!

I have made a library crate (initially a binary crate but changed it later to lib crate which i explain later in this text) which builds a staticlib with a custom target spec.
i have written a basic bootloader and compiled it using
`nasm -f elf64 -o boot.o boot.asm`
Real problem starts when im trying to call the
`kmain` function from my boot.asm using `extern kmain` and `call kmain` because of linking issues.

I am using the nightly build of rust
and have configured my .cargo/config.toml to build core crate and compiler_builtins as well
my kernel worked well when I linked it against elf file produced by `cargo rustc -- --emit=obj`
but when i was trying to use panic!() I ran across linker errors so i decided to use staticlib and link it with my boot.o because my emitted obj file didn't contain reference to a `core::panic::*` symbol

custom_target.json

```
{
    "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
    "arch": "x86_64",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "64",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "executables": true,
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "disable-redzone": true,
    "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

my Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "ordinal_system"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
"x86_64" = "0.14.10"

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"

[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]
path="src/kernel.rs"
```

This is my linkerscript:

```
SECTIONS {
    . = 0x7c00;

    .text :
    {
        os/boot.o(.bootsector)
        . = 0x7c00+510;
        SHORT(0xaa55)
        .=0x7e00;
        os/libordinal_system.a(.text);
    }

    .data :
    {
        os/libordinal_system.a(.data)
    }

    .bss :
    {
        os/libordinal_system.a(.bss)
    }

    .rodata :
    {
        os/libordinal_system.a(.rodata)
    }

}
```

I have compiled my boot.asm using `nasm -f elf64 -o boot.o os/boot.asm`
next I ran `cargo build --release` and `cp target/custom_target/release/libordinal_system.a os/`.

After this i use my linkerscript to link these two by doing
`ld.lld -T linker.ld os/boot.o os/libordinal_system.a -o os/boot.bin`

However I ran across this error

```
ld.lld: error: linker.ld:7: unable to move location counter backward for: .text
ld.lld: error: linker.ld:7: unable to move location counter backward for: .text
ld.lld: error: section .text at 0x16CA4 of size 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF115C exceeds available address space
ld.lld: error: section .rodata..Lanon.8d34b9bd859d642988e4500c0514c713.23 file range overlaps with .text.rust_begin_unwind
>>> .rodata..Lanon.8d34b9bd859d642988e4500c0514c713.23 range is [0xDEE, 0xE2B]
>>> .text.rust_begin_unwind range is [0xE00, 0xE31]

ld.lld: error: section .text.rust_begin_unwind file range overlaps with .rodata.cst8
>>> .text.rust_begin_unwind range is [0xE00, 0xE31]
>>> .rodata.cst8 range is [0xE2C, 0xF03]

ld.lld: error: section .rodata.cst8 file range overlaps with .text.kmain
>>> .rodata.cst8 range is [0xE2C, 0xF03]
>>> .text.kmain range is [0xE40, 0xE5A]

ld.lld: error: section .rodata..Lanon.8d34b9bd859d642988e4500c0514c713.26 file range overlaps with .text._ZN4core3net6parser52_$LT$impl$u20$core..net..socket_addr..SocketAddr$GT$11parse_ascii17h85f8204dc16520e9E
>>> .rodata..Lanon.8d34b9bd859d642988e4500c0514c713.26 range is [0xF04, 0xF29]
>>> .text._ZN4core3net6parser52_$LT$impl$u20$core..net..socket_addr..SocketAddr$GT$11parse_ascii17h85f8204dc16520e9E range is [0xF10, 0xF36]

ld.lld: error: section .text._ZN4core3net6parser52_$LT$impl$u20$core..net..socket_addr..SocketAddr$GT$11parse_ascii17h85f8204dc16520e9E file range overlaps with .rodata..Lanon.8d34b9bd859d642988e4500c0514c713.32
...
```

and it continued to produce more overlap errors.

Comment: You should probably explore the `ALIGN` directive of the linker script, where you can specify the starting pointer of the specific sections -- to avoid overlapping of data storage in memory.

Comment: It seems to work after modifying my linker script and kernel code to cut some calls to print(), I suspect I'm not loading enough sectors. I have tried changing the sector count to 100 but it fails to load anything when the number is going above 70 is there a limit of sorts when loading from floppy?
this is my repo link if you're interested in seeing the code: 
https://github.com/kushurox/OS

edit: apologies, I have just noticed that sector count cannot be greater than 128
I will modify this and if everything works fine ill post it as the answer. Thank you!